# Deleting dataframes containing only NAs from list r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a question regarding filtering elements of lists. I have a list containing 3000 elements, which are all dataframes. They all contain some NA values. However, some of these dataframes contain **only** NA values. How do I drop these particular elements from the list, such that they are not empty elements of the list, but don't exist in the list at all. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be the following:

```
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- iris
df3 <- data.frame(NA, NA)

my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)        
    
my_list[!sapply(seq_len(length(my_list)), function (i) all(is.na(my_list[[i]])))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if `any` is not `is.na` (or all are NA) and subset the list with the result

```
L[sapply(L, function(x) any(!is.na(x)))]
#L[!sapply(L, function(x) all(is.na(x)))] #Alternative
#[[1]]
#  a  b
#1 1 NA
```

Example dataset:

```
L <- list(data.frame(a=1, b=NA), data.frame(a=NA, b=NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Filter` -

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), list_df)
```

Or `keep` and `discard` from `purrr` -

```
purrr::keep(list_df, ~any(!is.na(.x)))
purrr::discard(list_df, ~all(is.na(.x)))
```